# Does "higher symmetry" mean any symmetry group of higher order?

Tags: physical-chemistry, group-theory

What is the precise definition of a higher symmetry in group theory? I see this term scattered around, such as in Cotton's *Chemical Applications of Group Theory*:

> ...In the cyclic groups each of the operations, *C<sub>n</sub>, C<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup>, C<sub>n</sub><sup>3</sup>, ..., , C<sub>n</sub><sup>n-1</sup>*, constitutes a class by itself and we continue to use this notations. However, in all other groups of **higher symmetry**, the number of classes spanned by these operations will be reduced in the following way...

Does higher symmetry strictly mean a supergroup? Or is it a quantitative statement about something like the number of symmetry elements or number of irreducible representations (which are not always ordered the same way, as in the case of *C<sub>3v</sub>* and *S<sub>4</sub>*).

I am failing to find intuition because, if it does mean strictly supergroups, we can't compare the "amount" of symmetry in *C<sub>2</sub>* compared to *C<sub>3</sub>* (or *T<sub>d</sub>* compared to *C<sub>i</sub>* even!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Higher symmetry" *per se* **does not mean anything**, unless you define it to mean something.

Depending on the context, it usually means one of the following things:

1. Any symmetry that is a supergroup of the group in question. In this case $C_{4v}$ is higher than $C_4$, while $C_6$ is *incomparable* to both. Bear with it. [Partially ordered sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) are quite a thing in math.
2. (rarely used) Any symmetry group having more elements than the group in question, so that $C_{4v}$ is higher than $C_6$, which in turn is higher than $C_4$.
3. (apparently, the meaning used by Cotton) Any symmetry group which is not a cyclic rotation group. In this case $C_{4v}$ is higher, while $C_4$ and $C_6$ are lower.

See, there is an intuition, after all. Worse yet, there are quite a few *different* kinds of intuition.

So it goes.